# Pandas not changing legend label

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot my data, however pandas uses the column label which I need to override in the legend. I thought the label keyword would change this, but it seems to have no effect. Googling shows that this was a bug in the 0.15 version, but I have 0.25 now. Does anyone know of a way around this?

Sample code:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(list(range(2,513, 2)), columns=['x'])
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(256), columns=['y'])
df = pd.concat([x, y], axis=1)
df = df.set_index(['x'])
df.plot(label='Random')
```

I would expect the legend to then list 'Random' as label for the curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the labels are created automatically from the series names. You can rename your `y` series before plotting as a workaround, ie.:

```
df.y.rename('Random').plot(legend=True)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea! I am taking the data out of a MultiIndex DF, but saving the slice and renaming the column works well. I tried this and the legend was completely gone - adding `plt.legend(loc='upper center')` made it show up though.

Comment: It may be necessary to enable the legend explicitly: `.plot(legend=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas plotting functionalities rely on matplotlib. You can use standard matplotlib functions to set labels, legend, etc.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = pd.DataFrame(list(range(2,513, 2)), columns=['x'])
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(256), columns=['y'])
df = pd.concat([x, y], axis=1)
df = df.set_index(['x'])
df.plot()
plt.legend(['Random'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I'm actually trying to change the label in the legend, not on the x-axis. Unfortunately, passing a list to set_legend directly also isn't working for me.

Comment: You have to pass a list. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed few years ago [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9542).

And in your case what you need is to specify the column to plot on y-axis

```
x = pd.DataFrame(list(range(2,513, 2)), columns=['x'])
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(256), columns=['y'])
df = pd.concat([x, y], axis=1)
df = df.set_index(['x'])
df.plot(y='y',label='Random')
```